# Can a T-SQL variable represent an entire row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

I'm coding for SQL Server 2008 R2. I have two databases that contains dozens of tables.

Each table in one database contains a table with the same name in the other database.

Tables with the same name have identical format (fields and data types). The contents of the two tables are similar but not identical. I need to update one based on changes made to the other, but only under certain circumstances. I think I want to use a cursor for this, but I can't find a good example to go by.

So far, the MSDN examples are reading one field at a time into a variable. I *do* need to be able to read/modify two columns which are identical in each table, but I gotta believe there's something less tedious than declaring variables for every column of every table.

I would *like* to be able to FETCH an entire row, check a couple of columns and then make a decision of whether I want to write the entire row to the other table after changing two columns - but do I have to declare variables for EVERY field I want to fetch / write? There's no way to just FETCH an entire row and write an entire row?

Comment: There is no version `10` or `2010` of SQL Server - you have 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012  - so which one is it??

Comment: Unless you have some very complex logic there's more than likely a way to do what you need in the joins and where in either a merge statement or basic update. Can you give some details about what you are checking?

Comment: @marc_s: I'd assume he's referring to 2008 (10.0) or 2008 R2 (10.5).

Comment: @marc_s I think he's referring to the server version no, you can view this using `SELECT @@VERSION`, eg for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 this returns `10.0.5512.0`

Comment: Ah, sorry...it's 2008 R2 vs 10.50.4000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could create a temporary table and insert the row there, but I think the `MERGE` command, which is very configurable and fast, should help you here.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can

```
select a.*
```

but cannot

```
set a.* = b.*
```

You don't need a cursor.  A set operation should do this better.
But the syntax is tedious.
Could you use .NET to build up the syntax?

```
update a 
set a.col1 = b.col1, a.col2 == b.col12, a.col3 = b.col3 
from table as a
join table as b 
  on a.ID is b.ID 
where a.col1 <> b.col1 or a.col12 <> b.col2
```